# Is there a way to dereference a list in common lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, dereference

Is there a way to dereference a list in lisp?

I am trying to compare 2 strings but one is in a list.

Comment: To be clear, you should probably mention common lisp in the title as well as the tags. The first version of my answer covered Scheme, Common Lisp and Clojure because I didn't notice the tag until afterward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want `car`. If your second structure looks like `'("string")`, then you want

```
(car '("string"))
```

If the string is not the first element in the list, you probably want (for example)

```
(nth 2 '(1 symbol "string"))
```

Remember to compare strings you want `equal`, not `=` which is for numbers only.